# Cancan doesn't always show authorized link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, cancan

I'm using Cancan to control `User` abilities, and have recently run into an odd issue: my partial has a "destroy" hyperlink that shows up only sometimes for authorized users. When I refresh the page, there's no telling whether the link will exist or not.

I've defined abilities for my `Event` model in `Ability.rb` in the following way:

```
can [:create, :update, :destroy], Event do |event|
    user.regattas(true).include?(event.regatta)
end
```

I use `regattas(true)` to prevent the system from using the cached associations, in case something's changed recently.

In my rspec tests, this works great for the current user, both in my tests for `Ability.rb` and my `EventsController` tests.

Here's the destroy. destroy hyperlink in my `_event.html.erb` partial, that I only want to appear when the user has the ability to destroy `event`:

```
<% if can? :destroy, event %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
<% end %>
```

Any advice for how fix the flickering, and get the "Destroy" link to ALWAYS show up for authorized users? Has anyone else run into this issue?

More background: I don't have this issue for another piece of code, not in a partial, shown here:

```
<% if can? :update, @regatta %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit Regatta Info', edit_regatta_path(@regatta) %> |
<% end %>
```

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryan Bates actually answered this one for me, on this [cancan github issue](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues#issue/205). Looks like Cancan has a known issue with models using `default_scope`, documented [on this ticket](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/issue/101). In my case, `event.rb` included a call to `default_scope`. Taking that line out completely fixed the issue.

The discussion on [the second ticket](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/issue/101) indicated that this was an issue with Ruby on Rails, as discussed in this [lighthouse ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5497-default-scope-and-class-reloading).

Hope this helps anyone else with this strange issue! Thanks, Ryan... I'll switch the answer over to you, if you happen to post on this.